# How to pass List from java to Oracle Procedure?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I want to send a List from java to Oracle procedure.
Forexample,
There is a school and the school has a list of students.
Also, the students have a list of lectures.
I create a list of lectures, 
and a list of students who has the list of lectures, 
and a school has a list of the students.

The Lectures.

```
ArrayList<String> lecture1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    lecture1.add("Mat");
    lecture1.add("physics");

    ArrayList<String> lecture2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    lecture2.add("English");
    lecture2.add("Spanish");

    ArrayList<String> lecture3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    lecture3.add("Germany");
    lecture3.add("French");
```

The list of lectures.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lectureList1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    lectureList1.add(lecture1);
    lectureList1.add(lecture3);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lectureList2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    lectureList2.add(lecture2);
    lectureList2.add(lecture3);
```

And the list of students who have lectures.

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> StudentList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    StudentList.addAll(lectureList2);
    StudentList.addAll(lectureList2);
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> StudentList2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    StudentList2.addAll(lectureList1);
    StudentList2.addAll(lectureList2);
```

And the school

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> school = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
    school.add(StudentList2);
    school.add(StudentList);
```

i want to send "**school**" to an oracle procedure. However I couldn't send a list directly. Oracle library allow to send array but I want to send list.

How can I do this operation? Could you help me.

Thanks.

Comment: convert your list to array using `toArray`and then pass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your lists to a mutli-dimensional array and then you can do something like:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE stringlist AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/

CREATE TYPE stringlist_list AS TABLE OF stringlist;
/

CREATE TYPE stringlist_list_list AS TABLE OF stringlist_list;
/

CREATE PROCEDURE load_list (
  in_list IN stringlist_list_list
)
AS
BEGIN
  NULL; -- Do something with the list
END;
/
```

**Java**:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;

public class TestDatabase2 {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","username","password");

      // Convert your lists to arrays using #toArray( T[] )

      String[] l1 = { "Math", "Physics" };
      String[] l2 = { "English", "Spanish" };
      String[] l3 = { "French", "German" };

      ArrayDescriptor des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("STRINGLIST_LIST_LIST", con);

      ARRAY school = new ARRAY( des, con, newString[][][]{
        new String[][]{ l1, l3 },
        new String[][]{ l2, l3 }
      } );

      CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall("{ call add_school( :school )}");

      // Passing an array to the procedure - 
      ((OracleCallableStatement) st).setARRAYAtName( "school", school );

      st.execute();
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```