# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, ora-00907

I'm trying to run this query, but I've got an error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I reviewed the statement but the parenthesis are right. I removed the last line of query and it works:

```
AND TN.LAST_UPDATEDATE > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL ? MINUTE)
```

maybe can be something in the '>' oparator, but I can't do this whithout it.

Code:

```
String sql= "SELECT DID.ORDER_ID "
            + "FROM TEST_ORDER DID, TEST_ORDER_SG DOS, TEST_HRD_SHIPS_GRP DHSG, TEST_INFO CSI "
            + "WHERE DID.ORDER_ID = DOS.ORDER_ID "
            + "AND DOS.SHIPPING_GROUPS = DHSG.SHIPPING_ID "
            + "AND DOS.SHIPPING_GROUPS = CSI.SHIPPING_ID "
            + "AND DHSG.TRACKING_CODE IS NULL AND CSI.SHIPPING_CARRIER IN "
            + "(?) "
            + "AND DID.STATE IN (?) "
            + "AND NOT EXISTS "
            + "("
            + "SELECT 1 FROM "
            + "CLIENT_INTEGRATION.TEST_LOG_ORDERS_STATUS TN "
            + "WHERE TN.ORDER_ID = DID.ORDER_ID AND TN.STATE = DID.STATE "
            + "AND TN.LAST_UPDATEDATE > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL ? MINUTE)"
            + ")";
```

Code to bind the parameters:

```
int actualIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    actualIndex = sql.indexOf('?', actualIndex+1);
    Class classe = params[i].getClass();

    if(classe.isArray()) {
        StringBuffer newPlaceHolders = new StringBuffer();

        int arrayLength = java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(params[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++) {

            if (j>0) {
                newPlaceHolders.append(",?");                        
            } else {
                newPlaceHolders.append("?");                        
            }
        }

        sql = sql.substring(0, actualIndex) + newPlaceHolders + sql.substring(actualIndex+1);
        actualIndex += newPlaceHolders.length();
    }

    if (actualIndex == -1) {
           break;
    }
}
```

So in another method I fill with some for loops, cause in some cases, the parameters (who are in a properties file) can be more than one.

```
int i=1;
    for(String carriers : getCarrier()) {
        ps.setString(i, carriers);              
        i++;
    }

    for(String state : getAllStates()) {
        ps.setString(i, state);
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INTERVAL ? MINUTE` is not valid.

The syntax is `INTERVAL '1' MINUTE` (and you cannot specify a variable for the value).

If you want to specify a variable you need to use [`TO_DSINTERVAL()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions184.htm)

Something like:

```
TO_DSINTERVAL( '0 00:' || TO_CHAR( ?, 'FM00' ) || ':00' )
```

**An aside**

You appear to be passing lists into the query by modifying the query to take multiple bind variables; you don't need to do this. Instead you can pass in an Oracle collection as a single bind variable. An example of this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37161584/1509264) (slightly more complicated as that example is for multi-dimensional arrays) but there is a simpler example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264).

Answer (score 0):

The final condition of the `WHERE` clause in the subquery should look something like this:

```
AND TN.LAST_UPDATEDATE > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '10' MINUTE)
```

You need to place the time amount in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution that using `interval` or `to_dsinterval()` is to use direct date arithmetic. You can add or subtract numbers to/from a datetime or timestamp; the number is expressed in days, so if your input (shown as ?) is in minutes, you must divide by 24*60. Like so:

```
... and tn.last_update > current_timestamp - ? / 24 * 60
```

Please note that this will change the right-hand side into a date/time (no fractional seconds), so it won't work if you need fractions of a second.